# Unable to build ToaruOS from source into .iso file

Tags: docker, github, visual-studio-code, operating-system, open-source

I am currently trying to run a docker command

`` docker run -v `pwd`:/root/misaka -w /root/misaka -e LANG=C.UTF-8 -t toaruos/build-tools:1.99.x util/build-in-docker.sh ``

It always throws an error like: No such file or directory found, but issue here is that the that file is alerady existing

Error :
`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "util/build-in-docker.sh": stat util/build-in-docker.sh: no such file or directory: unknown.`

And one last thing actually i am using a github project :
 [klange/toaruos](https://github.com/klange/toaruos)
its a os project my problem is how to build this source into .iso file.
Can anyone explain me the process.

build process is given but i am unable to run each command and more there nothing mentioned about how to build ToaruOS from source into a .iso file